# how to resolve OCI-04030?

Tags: oracle, tomcat, windows-7

how to resolve OCI-04030 ?

OS : window 7 32-bit
web server : tomcat 6.0

Comment: What are you running on Tomcat to run out of process memory?

Comment: you need to give more details such as memory settings, detailed error stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

When we experience Tomcat memory problems it's almost always caused by issues with thread pools and we have to look for threads not terminating or being released properly.

Comment: i can solve it myself. cos i don't run as administrator in windows 7